# Why is word inserting dots into output of RTF file

Tags: ms-word, rtf

I am replacing text in RTF documents for a mail merge and have come across a problem with Microsoft Word 2010, I assume the same is occuring in earlier versions of Word.
The problem is Word is duplicating paragraphs and inserting "..." at the start of the paragraph.

I would like to know why this is happening? Seaching the raw text does not find a string with three dots. I assume there is an error in the formatting or structure of the text?

Note that opening the same document in Libre Office or Open office does not have the dots or duplicated paragraphs.

An example document can be found here http://pastebin.com/1kBzS3FP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I found a group with a control word on a new line by itself. Removing the preceding newline character from the control word fixed up the duplicate paragraphs and dots.
See the below script for more details.

Before:

```
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 
\insrsid2363036 
\par }
```

After:

```
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2363036 
\par }
```

As for why Word reacts this way to a control word on a new line, well that's a question for the Microsoft developers.